# I can enter my homepage but can't enter wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, web, server, wp-admin

I build a wordpress site, for a time there was no problem but recently i can't enter my wp-admin page. I tried plugin,themes thing. I get this error but i dont know that it means. Can u help ?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Error::has_errors() in /var/www/html/wp-login.php:50 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/wp-login.php(937): login_header('Log In', '', Object(WP_Error)) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/wp-login.php on line 50
```

Comment: Sounds like your WordPress setup has been corrupted. Try reuploading all WordPress core files to your server, then I suggest you install an anti-malware/security plugin to run a scan just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Update your wp-login file with default Wordpress wp-login file.

Comment: i did but now i can't log in it says "sorry you are not allowed to access this page"

Comment: After Update your file increase memory limit by config file